# How to enter special characters in MS Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio, character

I need to enter division sign: ÷ 
Where can I find that and other special characters?

I am using Windows

Comment: What system are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Simplestvway is to Copy-Paste it.